# Sql Connection string and cant parameters visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

```
Using System.data.SqlClient;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Antoni Angga\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\FullAndStarving\\FullAndStarving\\FaD.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into TabelProduksi(IdProduksi,IdPhoto,Tanggal Produksi,Nama Karyawan,Keterangan Photo,Photo) Values(@IdProduksi,@IdPhoto,@Tanggal Produksi,@Nama Karyawan,@Keterangan Photo,@Photo)", con);
            con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProduksi",txtIdpro.Text);
            con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPhoto",txtIdPhoto.Text);
            con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tanggal Produksi",dtmProduksi.Value);
            con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama Karyawan", txtNamaKaryawan.Text);
            con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keterangan Photo", rxtKtrphoto.Text);

            con.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
```

can you help me that parameters on that cant find ?
why ?
and that connection string true now ?
because i use local sql server :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column names have more than one word, you need to use them with square brackets as `[Tanggal Produksi]` and `[Nama Karyawan]` etc. But I would suggest to change them in one word. And it would be better to keep your parameter names one word as well.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var comm = con.CreateCommand())
{
   com.CommandText = @"insert into TabelProduksi(IdProduksi,IdPhoto,[Tanggal Produksi],[Nama Karyawan],[Keterangan Photo],Photo) 
                       Values(@IdProduksi,@IdPhoto,@TanggalProduksi,@NamaKaryawan,@KeteranganPhoto,@Photo)";
   // Add your parameters with Add method.
   con.Open();
   comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

By the way, based on their names, your `IdProduksi` and `IdPhoto` columns should be some numeric type instead of character typed.

Comment: and my connection is true now sir ?
thanks before :D

Comment: @AntoniAngga I can't be 100% sure about that. Just connect your server with Visual Studio and check `Server Explorer` window properties. It shows your connection string as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take the spaces out of your fields and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you have used the wrong parameter name in your query it should be like

```
 SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into TabelProduksi(IdProduksi,IdPhoto,TanggalProduksi,NamaKaryawan,Keterangan Photo,Photo) Values(@IdProduksi,@IdPhoto,@TanggalProduksi,@NamaKaryawan,@KeteranganPhoto,@Photo)", con);
```

You have to also change it from `con.Parameters.AddWithValue`